# Is 'sluttish time' a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors, shakespeare, literary-english, poetic

The phrase 'sluttish time' is used by Shakespeare in one of his sonnets. Can it be termed as a transferred epithet as the word 'sluttish' here seems to be an epithet(adjective) or is it essentially a metaphor?

Comment: Sluttish time:(with sluttish time) (4): i.e., by filthy time.
In Elizabethan England the word "sluttish" could describe either a sexually promiscuous woman or a grubby, unkempt woman. Here Shakespeare personifies Time as the latter. http://www.shakespeare-online.com/sonnets/55detail.html

Comment: O! So, do you mean it's neither metaphor nor transferred epithet but simply personification?

Comment: Hi Archna - it has nothing to do with personification.  It's just a adjective.  Like "horrible" "pleasant" "fast" "slow".  Really in terms of the taxonomy of the phrase, it's nothing more than a noun with an adjective.

Comment: Josh - just FTR,  ("this is not a literary criticism site!") for me it immediately also suggests the "money-grubbing" aspect ..  time takes from you, takes and takes, just like a prostitute or a grasping wife; it offers you only shallow fake beauty .. and so on. Anyway: neither here nor there in the issue at hand.

Comment: This isn't literary criticism? Just clarifying which poetic device can be applied here?

Comment: Hi Archna - I was talking to Josh, forget that comment :)

Answer (score 1):

About 150 years after Shakespeare published the sonnet under discussion here, Samuel Johnson, *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1756) included these definitions of *slut* and *sluttish*:

> SLUT, *s.* {*slodde*, Dutch} 1. A dirty woman. *King.* 2. A word of slight contempt to a woman. *L'Estrange.*
>
> SLUTTISH, a. Nasty; not nice; not cleanly; dirty; indecently negligent of cleanliness. *Raleigh.*

Evidently in Shakespeare's time *slut* and *sluttish* were understood in much the same way that *slattern* and *slatternly* were—as referring to a person (usually a woman) who paid insufficient attention to cleanliness. *Sluttish* might therefore also be associated with notions of unkemptness or slovenliness, as well as of actual dirtiness. Obviously, these are not actual characteristics of time, understood as an abstract though measurable entity. And yet "sluttish time" isn't a metaphor for time; a metaphor would be something like "sluttish drab" standing in for "time" (if *drab* is used in one of its two early senses of "slattern" or "prostitute").

In a comment beneath Joe Blow's answer, the poster provides a definition of *transferred epithet*, a term I was not familiar with:

> A transferred epithet often involves shifting a modifier from the animate to the inanimate, as in the phrases "cheerful money," "sleepless night," and "suicidal sky."

Given the close connection of *slut* and *sluttish* with specifically human (and more specifically female) hygiene, I think it is fair to say that "sluttish time" qualifies as a transferred epithet, as the poster defines that term. "Sluttish" would perhaps be even more obviously a normally animate modifier if it meant "indiscriminately promiscuous," as it does today. "Sluttish time" may also qualify as personification, depending on how you define that term. *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this as its primary definition:

> **personification** *n* **1 :** attribution of personal qualities; *esp* : representation of a thing or abstraction as a person or by the human form

In the sonnet, Shakespeare attributes a personal quality (sluttishness) to time, but he does not represent time in human form (as he might have done with a phrase such as "that sluttish fishwife, time"). It therefore seems to me that of the terms suggested by the poster—*metaphor*, *transferred epithet*, and *personification*—the one that best fits "sluttish time" is *transferred epithet*.

Answer (score 0):

A metaphor is: "a figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable:"

It's a close call, but I really would **not** call it a "metaphor" in this case. Sluttish just means "grubby" or "dirty".

Metaphors are things like "the world is a stage."  [examples](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/metaphor-examples-for-kids.html)

"dirty" is just an adjective ... dirty time. Generally metaphors tend to be nouns: you're describing something, as, some other thing.  So, "the office is like a jail" "the business is like a fast train" "the family was like a zoo" etc etc.

So,

(A) as a rule, metaphors are "things" ("her emotions were like ice / steel / bubblegum" etc) - I can't really think of many "adjective metaphors".

(B) even if you allow "adjective metaphors", time is a very unusual thing (among other problems, it has basically no definition or meaning; it is epistemologically challenged). I can't see anything more unusual, "less real" about describing time as greedy, angry, lovely, etc, than describing it as perhaps "fast" or "slow" (how can you have fast or slow time - it's meaningless really).

For example: say the phrase at hand was "horrible time". You wouldn't ask if that's a metaphor, it's just a noun with an adjective. In this case, it's a very colourful, unusual, indeed Shakespearean adjective, laden to overflowing with meaning and thought.   But then, he's Shakespeare ... consider our salad days.

---

Also FTR you mention epithet.  An epithet is, very simply, a **commonly-used** adjective for some particular thing. There's really no connection here to epithets.

Comment: That is what is confusing. As per definition: A transferred epithet often involves shifting a modifier from the animate to the inanimate, as in the phrases "cheerful money," "sleepless night," and "suicidal sky."  So, considering this, can 'sluttish time' be called a transferred epithet?

Comment: There's nothing confusing.  "dirty" is literally and perfectly applicable to "time", and that's that.  Secondly, a survey of metaphors shows that they are **nouns** (I'm as fat as a **pig**, as silly as a **goose** and so on): there is just no tradition of "adjective-metaphors," it doesn't parse really.

Comment: I have no idea what a "transferred epithet" is, it sounds like something made-up for a text book hat has never been used.

Comment: "epithet" means almost nothing. It means little more than "a common adjective" or "the **usual** adjective" for something.  So, the internet is "stupid", programmers are "late", Scotland is "beautiful" etc.  Really, there's no connection to an epithet here - an epithet would be "an adjective people very often use to describe time".

Comment: BTW regarding epithets.  ""cheerful money," "sleepless night," and "suicidal sky."" are not epithets (I've never heard them before).  for "money" you often hear "dirty money" - I guess you'd say "dirty ..." is a typical epithet for money.

Comment: I never said they are epithets. They are transferred epithets. And they are called so exactly for that reason because these epithets (cheerful, sleepless etc.) are not commonly used to describe the said nouns.

Comment: Fair enough - I have never heard the term. Thanks for that!

Comment: Good evening :) This is a hypallage.

Answer (score 0):

You speak of metaphors when a normal word A, mostly a noun, is replaced by another noun B and you can see what is meant because A is in some respect comparable to B.

You can speak of oil or petroleum or you can use a metaphor as black gold. In the metaphor the word oil or petroleum does not appear.

Shakespeare speaks of time and only  uses a special adjective that is not usually used in connection with time. But the noun time is not replaced by a substitute noun, so this isn't a metaphor. Of course, the special use of the adjective is a literary device and I'm sure rhetorics or stylistics has a name for it. But I'm not so much interested in the hundreds of terms in stylistics and I dont know it.